# unfolding lists in ML

Tags: sml, smlnj

hello everyone I'm trying to write function which can unfold int in the list from any depth, for example if I have following `bigList: [12, [34], [11,[1]]]` I want to receive

```
[(1,12),(2,34),(3,11),(4,1)]
```

first element in tuple is the depth and the second is the number
I wrote this code:

```
datatype 'a bigList = Empty of unit
   | Element of 'a
   | List of 'a bigList list;


local
fun unfolder( Empty , n ) = []
 | unfolder( (Element l)::ls, n ) = (n, l)::unfolder( ls, n )
 | unfolder( (List l)::ls, n) = unfolder( l, n + 1)::unfolder(ls, n)

in
fun flat list = unfolder(list, 1)  
end;
```

every time I receive the following error:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.71 [built: Thu Sep 17 08:50:14 2009]
- datatype 'a bigList = Element of 'a | Empty of unit | List of 'a bigList list
stdIn:9.5-11.69 Error: data constructor Empty used without argument in pattern
stdIn:11.33-11.69 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: (int * 'Z) list * (int * 'Z) list list
  operand:         (int * 'Z) list * (int * 'Z) list
  in expression:
    unfolder (l,n + 1) :: unfolder (ls,n)
-
```

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> data constructor Empty used without argument in pattern

You defined `Empty` as `Empty of unit`, which means you need to use it as `Empty ()`, which is pretty pointless. To use it as just `Empty`, you need to define it as `Empty` without the `of unit`.

> ```
> unfolder (l,n + 1) :: unfolder (ls,n)
> ```

The type of `::` is `'a * ['a] -> ['a]`, which means that the left operand must be a single element and the right operand a list. In the above both operands are a list, so you get a type error.

To concatenate two lists use the `@` operator, not `::`.